# How to just keep numbers and alphabets using pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, numeric, alphabet

If my series is:

```
 t=pd.Series(["Payment","('TransNum', '00')","('TransNum', '07')"])
```

Then how to use pandas (Python) to just keep numbers and alphabets so that it is like this:

```
t=pd.Series(["Payment","TransNum00","TransNum07"])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string operations for a pandas Series object has the `replace` method, which you can pass a regular expression to.

```
t = t.str.replace('[^\dA-Za-z]', '')
```